# Нужна ли запятая после и перед "что есть"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

У них ни слова в голове, и всё, что есть, — на ветер.

Answer (score 1):

Это текст песни https://www.gl5.ru/s/sted_d/cryogen.html

**У них ни слова в голове, и всё, что есть, — на ветер.**

Оформление правильное, запятыми обособлено придаточное предложение (местоименно-определительное). Перед тире запятая сохраняется.